# MySQL RAND() how often can it be used? does it use /dev/random?

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have a table with few rows (tops 50), I need to get random value out of table I can do that by 
 
`ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` 
Main question is in the point when I have 6k selects in 5 seconds is rand stil 'reliable'? 
How is rand calculated, can I seed it over time? (idk, every 5 seconds).

Comment: The biggest problem with `ORDER BY RAND` is not the randomness (although yes, that is a problem), but the fact that it kills your DB performance by forcing the DB to scan the entire table and throwing away all its indexes.

Comment: even with just 50 rows? I think its not that big deal (is it?).

Comment: no, if you're just talking about 50 rows, it's not a big deal. But likewise, if it's just 50 rows, you could just as easily remove mySQL's `RAND` from the equation entirely by loading the whole lot into an array and sorting it in your PHP code. I accept that PHP's random will have the same issues, but you could combine mySQL's `ORDER BY RAND` with PHP's `array_rand()`, and double-shuffle it using two different random algorithms. That should give you more entropy.

Comment: isn't it better to sort it out right in mysql? (the randomization of select), I like double shuffle idea and I was thinking about it, but still isn't there risk I run out of random values? :) and what about speed?
**mysql rand -> php rand** is sure more slower than just **mysql - rand**

Comment: Yes, it is better keeping it in mysql. The PHP option only really comes into play because it's such a small number of records in the table. Another option that works because it's a small table is to use PHP to randomise the `LIMIT` clause if you know in advance the num of records. But I guess the real answer depends on just how much of an issue it is for you to have a truly random (ie unpredictable) result: `ORDER BY RAND` may be perfectly sensible. Its not true random but if you've got multiple people making independent requests, it would be very hard for one user to predict independently.

Comment: I was just aware that mysql rand function can run out of random values (like /dev/random/ is limited), @BillKarwin mentioned that RAND is not reliable on /dev/random.
I can demonstrate my problem here: I have a website and about 12k users and on each request I need to generate random number to show random picture (its just a example), I was also thinking about pre-generating every night or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MySQL pseudo-random number generator is completely deterministic.  The docs say:

> RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator. It is a fast way to generate random numbers on demand that is portable between platforms for the same MySQL version.

It can't use /dev/random because MySQL is designed to work on a variety of operating systems, some of which don't have a /dev/random.

MySQL initializes a default seed at server startup, using the integer returned by `time(0)`.
If you're interested in the source line, it's in the MySQL source in file sql/mysqld.cc, function `init_server_components()`.  I don't think it ever re-seeds itself.

Then the subsequent "random" numbers are based solely on the seed.  See source file mysys_ssl/my_rnd.cc, function `my_rnd()`.

---

The best practice solution to your random-selection task, for both performance and quality of randomization, is to generate a random value between the minimum primary key value and maximum primary key value.  Then use that random value to select a primary key in your table:

```
SELECT ... FROM MyTable WHERE id > $random LIMIT 1
```

The reason you'd use > instead of = is that you might have gaps in the id due to rows being deleted or rolled back, or you might have other conditions in your WHERE clause so that you have gaps in between rows that match your conditions.

The disadvantages of this greater-than method:

- Rows following such a gap have a higher chance of being chosen, and the larger the gap the greater the chance.
- You need to know the MIN(id) and MAX(id) before you generate the random value.
- Doesn't work as well if you need more than one random row.

Advantages of this method:

- It's much faster than ORDER BY RAND(), even for a modest table size.
- You can use a random function outside of SQL.

Comment: based on your answer, mysqls rand function can not "run out of" random values (as it is not based on /dev/random), and it is based purely on initial seed, right? (no matter how fast I do selects 6 to 12k per 5 seconds)

Comment: Correct, it's just an arithmetic progression based on the seed.  I don't have rights to post the code here, but you should download MySQL's source and read the my_rnd() function I mentioned above.  It's only three lines long.

Answer (score 1):

RAND is pseudorandom. Be careful using it for security stuff. I don't think your "choose one row randomly out of fifty" is for security, so you're probably OK.

It's pretty fast for a small table. It will be horrible for picking a random row out of a large table:  it will has to tag every row with a pseudorandom number and then sort them.  For the application you're describing, @TheEwook's suggestion is exactly right; sorting even a small table more often than once a millisecond can swamp even powerful MySQL hardware.

Don't seed RAND, ever, unless you're testing and you want a repeatable sequence of random numbers for some kind of unit test. I learned this the hard way once when generating what I thought were hard-to-guess session tokens.  The MySQL guys did a good job with RAND and you can trust them for the application you're talking about.

I think (not sure), if you don't seed it, it starts with a random seed from /dev/random.

If you need crypto-grade random numbers, read /dev/random yourself.  But keep in mind that /dev/random can only generate a limited rate.  /dev/urandom uses /dev/random to generate a faster rate, but isn't as high-grade in its entropy pool.

Comment: its not going to be used for any security problems, your last paragraph is exactly why I wrote this question down. dev/random is not 'endless' (is limited) I need to generate tons of ('reliable') rand values well 6k is just a guess but sometimes select count may spike up to 12k or more...

Answer (score 0):

If your table is not too big (let's say max 1000 records) it doesn't really matter. But for big tables you must choose an alternative way.

This article may help you:

http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Comment: This answer does not really address the question about the entropy pool of `RAND()`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what about the fact where does rand gets it seed, when is it re-seeded ? (well the comment above is suited).

Answer (score 0):

`RAND()` never blocks, but the numbers it returns are not very randomly distributed.

> How is rand calculated

MySQL's `RAND()` used a multiplicative congruential pseudo-random number generator. It has two 30-bit variables as state; seed1 and seed2. Each time you call `RAND()`, it calculates new values by multiplying and adding, and returns seed1 converted to a floating point number between 0 and 1. The code looks as follows:

```
seed1 = (seed1 * 3 + seed2) % 0x3FFFFFFF
seed2 = (seed1 + seed2 + 33) % 0x3FFFFFFF
return seed1 / 0x3FFFFFFF
```

> MySQL RAND() how often can it be used?

It can be used indefinitely. It never blocks and always returns a number. After at most 83265600 iterations, it loops and starts outputting the same sequence.

> does it use /dev/random?

No. It does not use `/dev/random`, `/dev/urandom`, [getrandom()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html), or any other form of cryptographically secure random offered by the operating system.

> is rand stil 'reliable'?

It always returns a number between 0 and 1, but these numbers are not very random. Output of `RAND()` can be predicted, and when using `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` you may see some rows getting picked much more than other rows.

> can I seed it over time?

Yes, and this can improve its randomness. Seeding the PRNG used for `RAND()` is done with an SQL statement like this:

```
set session rand_seed1 = 123, rand_seed2 = 456;
```

Use two independent random numbers of at least 30 bits.

Alternatively, the function [`RANDOM_BYTES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_random-bytes) returns cryptographically secure random values. This function may be a bit harder to use in queries since it returns a string, but the values it returns are much more random than `RAND`.

I have more information on my blog: [MySQL's random number generator](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2024/01/17/mysql-mariadb-rand-random-number-generator/)