# Trying to Retrieve one random photo for each photo gallery as cover photo

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to display all photo galleries for a member. For each of those photo galleries I want to display a random photo from the gallery as the cover photo. I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.4 for this project. Originally I thought I could just run a foreach() loop in the controller, query a random photo, and add it to the object. However when doing that (current code is below) I get the following error "Attempt to assign property of non-object". This error occurs at the line where I try to add thumbnail to the $data['albums'] object.

```
public function index() {
    $data['albums'] = $this->album_model->get_many_by('profile_id', $this->member_id);
    // I need to grab a random photo to display
    foreach ($data['albums'] as $album) {
        $thumb = $this->photo_model->order_by('id', 'rand')->limit(1)->get_by('album_id', $album->id);
        $data['albums']->thumbnail = $thumb->thumbnail;
    }
    $data['current_albums'] = $this->album_model->count_by('profile_id', $this->member_id);
    $this->load->model('profile_model');
    $data['maximum_albums'] = $this->profile_model->with('membership')->get($this->member_id);
    $data['allowed_albums'] = $data['maximum_albums']->membership->albums - $data['current_albums'];
    $this->layout->title(site_name() . ' | My Albums');
    $this->layout->view('member/albums/index', $data);
}
```

How would I go about adding another value to the object, and is this even the best way to do this? I wasn't sure if doing this via MySQL would be best, plus I'm not sure how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$data['albums']` is not an object (which is why you can't set `->thumbnail` on it)

Comment: cast it as (object), but that wont solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_random_image() {

    $this->db->order_by('id', 'RANDOM'); //takes over randomness
    $this->db->limit(1); //gets only one record
    //$this->db->where(); //if needed
    $query = $this->db->get('images'); //from what table

    return $query->result_array();

}
```

RANDOM takes care of your "randomness" see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766420/mysql-rand-how-often-can-it-be-used-does-it-use-dev-random) about MySQL randomness itself.

---

to the comment:

```
foreach ($data['albums'] as $key => $album) {

    $thumb = $this->photo_model->order_by('id', 'rand')->limit(1)->get_by('album_id', $album->id);
    $data['albums'][$key]->thumbnail = $thumb->thumbnail;

}
```

Comment: Getting the photo is no problem, how do I add it to $data['albums'] as thumbnail so that I can display it in my view though?